# String search using suffix trees

Tags: string, algorithm, search

A suffix tree can be used to efficiently search a word in a set of words. Is suffix trees still the best method if:
1. the set of words is made from an infinite set of characters
2. the set of words is ordered alphabetically (or in a way that makes sense)?

Answer (score 0):

A suffix tree is an overkill if you just want search for a word in a set of words(and you do not need search for their substrings). A trie is a better choice(the time complexity is the same, but it is much simpler). If the words are ordered, you can use a binary search to find the word(yes, it does have an additional log n factor, but it is not that bad). Even if they are not ordered, you can sort them before searching for other words. This approach is good because it does not require any custom data structures and it usually has smaller constant and smaller memory usage(the space complexity is the same, but the constant is better).